# Other ways of creating a delay other than time.sleep() in python

Tags: python, time, delay, micropython

I am doing a bit of python on my casio calculator and i have run into a little problem, the version of python that my calculator uses is microPython 1.9.4. I am not able to use `import time` as the time module isn't in this version. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit: changed version to 1.9.4

My Code (the time.sleep() is near the bottom):

```py
import time
barriers = []
playerPosition = [11, 1]
playTime = 0
while playTime <= 0:
  line = 6
  while line >= 1:
    if line > 2:
      if playerPosition[1] != line:
        print("                     ")
      else:
        currentLine = ""
        xPosition = 1
        while xPosition < playerPosition[0]:
          currentLine = currentLine + " "
          xPosition = 1 + xPosition
        currentLine = currentLine + "|"
        xPosition = 1 + xPosition
        while xPosition < 21:
          currentLine = currentLine + " "
          xPosition = 1 + xPosition
    else:
      obstructions = []
      obstructions.clear()
      if playerPosition[1] == line:
        obstructions.append(playerPosition[0])
      for barrier in barriers:
        obstructions.append(barrier)
      obstructions.sort()
      currentLine = ""
      nextObstruction = 0
      xPosition = 1
      while xPosition <= 21:
        try:
          if xPosition != obstructions[nextObstruction]:
            currentLine = currentLine + " "
          else:
            currentLine = currentLine + "|"
            nextObstruction = 1 + nextObstruction
        except:
          currentLine = currentLine + " "
        xPosition = 1 + xPosition
      print(currentLine)
    line = line - 1
  barrierID = 0
  while barrierID < len(barriers):
    if barriers[barrierID] > 1:
      barriers[barrierID] = barriers[barrierID] - 1
    else:
      barriers.remove(barrierID)
  time.sleep(0.5)
  playTime = 1 + playTime
```

Comment: Instead of importing `time`, does importing `utime` work?

Comment: The corresponding micropython module is ``utime``: https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/utime.html Just doing Replacing ``import time`` with ``import utime as time`` should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Micropython doesn't include the `time` module, however it does have a module called `utime` which implements a smaller subset of standard python's `time` module, luckily including `sleep`.

So, all you need to do is:

- change `import time` to `import utime`
- and change `time.sleep(0.5)` to `utime.sleep(0.5)`

You can find the documentation for `utime` at http://docs.micropython.org/en/v1.9.1/pyboard/library/utime.html.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I am told that there is no module named utime. i have just realised that i am running micropython 1.9.4 not 1.9.1, which may be why it isn't working. If so, are there any other ways?

Answer (score 1):

We can make our own custom sleep function using the inbuilt `rtc` module like so that takes microseconds as a value.

```
import machine
def sleep(microseconds):
    """sleep(microseconds)
    Delay execution for a given number of microseconds."""
    rtc = machine.RTC()
    rtc.init((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    if microseconds < 0:
        raise ValueError("microseconds must not be negative")
    start = rtc.now()[6]
    while rtc.now()[6] - start < microseconds:
        pass
```

We can then add use this code by removing the import for `time` and simply using sleep with the value in microseconds, 0.5 seconds being 500000 microseconds.

```
sleep(500000)
```

Comment: @finlaymorrison, made a mistake, have to import `machine`

Comment: @finlaymorrison Ah, That's great! If I'm totally honest I didn't 100% expect it to work myself! You might want to consider pressing the green tick next to my answer to mark it as fixing your issue :-).

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't a time library, you could try a for loop to simulate a delay:

```
for x in range(10000000):
    pass
```

Comment: This is dependant on the processor clock speed and will not be accurate.